# Dealing with different densities and equal resolution

Tags: android

I have tested my app on 2 devices:

HTC HD2 (480x800, density=192)

HTC Sensation XL (480x800, density=240)

When I start the app on HD2, everything looks nice, but when looking on Sensation, it's a tragedy.

ImageButtons, TextViews, ImageViews, everything becomes very, very big...

HD2 and Sensation both are "normal-hdpi" for Android system, not paying attention that the difference is about 50 pixels. It uses xml files which are in the "res/layout-normal-hdpi" folder for both tests.

So the question is, how to deal with this? How to keep it look nicely?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The Sensation XL ought to be large-hdpi, with its 4.7-inch screen, and the HD2 is on the cusp. It ought to have a few more dp than the HD2, if not, the fault lies with whomever developed the ROM image on your Sensation. According to the dpi calculator I wrote in Python a while ago, the HD2 has a dpi of 216, and the Sensation a dpi of 198 - it may be normal because you have the DPI set too high, so it thinks the screen is smaller, in which case it's almost certainly a ROM issue unless you've manually changed the dpi.

With that in mind, defining sizes in terms of dp may be a solution - dp are meant to be the same size on any screen. For TextView, use sp to set the text size. If the phones' sizes are set properly in their ROM images, this will fix the scaling issues you're having.